# MediaGroups across multiple windows?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

So the goal is to open a new window, and add a video from the new window to a mediagroup that exists in a different one. I'm not having much luck, but if it's possible, I'd appreciate a nudge in the right direction. Here's what my code looks like so far.

```
        var one = document.getElementById("one");
        var two = document.getElementById("two");
        open = window.open('launched.html','SHOOP','height:756,width=1344,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no');
        var across = open.document.getElementById("across");
        across.mediaGroup = "test";
        one.mediaGroup = "test";
        two.mediaGroup = "test";
```

Something like that. Thanks in advance.